# MVC - Duvida sobre controller e view PHP

Tags: php, mvc, view, controller

Estou estudando MVC a alguns dias e me deparei com uma duvida, eu preciso de uma view para fazer cadastro, mas essa view não iria fazer nada apenas enviar os dados a minha duvida é que eu preciso de um controle só pra montar essa view e outro para cadastra-lo?

Comment: Na web o entendimento do MVC é um pouco diferente dos softwares que trabalham com sinais (como os aplicativos desktop). Quero dizer, qualquer requisição feita via HTTP precisa de um Controller.

Comment: Entendi, então eu devo criar um controle para montar o formulário e outro para receber esses dados.

Comment: Sim você está certo André, no caso um controller pode ter vários actions, então você pode ter um controller que acessa  um action, então você pode ter um controller apenas, mas com vários actions - uma duvida qual framework você está usando?

Comment: Não estou usando nenhum no momento é apenas para fins didáticos, pois prefiro entender primeiramente como funciona esse tipo de aplicação antes de usar os frameworks.

Comment: "montar um formulário"... isso está mais para helper.. pesquise por "html helper". Não é necessariamente uma library ou controller.

Comment: @DanielOmine uma boa dica, só um detalhe que tenho certeza que você sabe e é apenas para outros usuários não confundirem é que o "html helper" (ou equivalmente) deve ser usado dentro do View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As aplicações HTTP mudam um pouco em comparação com aplicações Desktop, por exemplo softwares em C++ que usam MVC tem suporte para sinal, então até um botão pode ser um "controller".

Já nos frameworks HTTP até a requisição a página index deve ser um Controller/action, exemplos:

### Laravel:

O Laravel assim como outros frameworks mais recentes, usam rotas para acessar os controllers, por exemplo:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
```

O Controller deve ser algo como:

```
<?php
class HomeController extends UserController
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('formulario');//Mostra o seu view
    }
}
```

Note que no exemplo o View não recebe dados do Model, mas provavelmente o formulário do Model vai acessar outro action dentro do `HomeController` (ou outro Controller) que usará um `Model`.

### cakePHP:

No cakephp você deve editar o arquivo `app/config/routes.php`, deve ficar algo como:

```
Router::connect('/', array(
                       'controller' => 'MeuController',
                       'action' => 'index'
                     ));
```

Este action `index` não precisa necessariamente acessar um Model, supondo que nele contenha o seu formulário

Supondo que o formulário aponte para uma página como `http://example/usuario/cadastrar` então você terá que adicionar uma rota assim:

```
Router::connect('/usuario/cadastrar', array(
                       'controller' => 'MeuController',
                       'action' => 'cadastrar'
                     ));
```

Ou outro Controller

```
Router::connect('/usuario/cadastrar', array(
                       'controller' => 'UserController',
                       'action' => 'cadastrar'
                     ));
```

Comment: Ah sim era isso que estava tentando entender, como não estou a utilizar nenhum framework, estava em duvida sobre ações que não recebem dados adicionais, muito obrigado.