# PHP utilizando MVC

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Estou criando uma aplicação em PHP (sem frameworks) utilizando o MVC, porém estou com muitas dúvidas, pois até hoje só utilizei o Symfony para fazer aplicações PHP. Tenho dúvidas quanto ao roteamento das urls e utilização das functions. Segue um exemplo de como está meu projeto atualmente:

Estrutura:

sistema-api

- pub

  - index.php
- src

  - Controller

    - UserController.php
  - Model

    - User.php
- Templates

  - index.html.twig

Arquivo UserController.php

```
class UserController{
    public function insertUser(){
        //execução

        return json_encode($resultado);
    }

    public function delteUser(){
        // execução

        return json_encode($resultado);
    }

}
```

Arquivo User.php

```
class User {

    public $id;
    public $name;

function getId(){
     return $this->id;
}
```

Minhas dúvidas são: Como faço o roteamento para acessar "api.exemplo/insertUser" (vou ter uma outra aplicação client que irá consumir essa api)

(Estou usando VirtualHost do Apache, direcionado para /var/www/sistema-api/pub )

Comment: Acho que vc deve procurar saber sobre PSR-4 autoloader: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/   ( Há também outros padrões )

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69178/mvc-duvida-sobre-controller-e-view-php

Comment: Obrigado pelos links!